# MAAS Cluster without juju and Openstack

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, cluster, beowulf

I couldn't find proper documentation about MAAS installation but finally I made my own MAAS server and 1 node and it is working now. My idea about MAAS was that nodes share their computing power with the cluster controller server but things are not working like this. Everyone including Ubuntu forcing users to install juju on MAAS cluster.

Does MAAS spread my workload automatically in terms of send workload to nodes. I don't want to use juju, charms & openstack.

Can I replace MAAS cluster with beowulf cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MAAS cluster is for mass-deploying individual nodes that you deploy services onto, there is no compute sharing between MAAS nodes.